# How does Force regenerate?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I've been playing my Sith Inquisitor and, though the resources for the other classes have been either self explanatory (Knight/Warrior) or have helpful info about regen rates on mouseover (the other 6), when I mouse over my "Force" bar, it only displays the amount of force I have remaining - both as a raw number and as a percentage.

What determines the rate of Force Regeneration? Is this listed somewhere on the UI like the other resources?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Force regerates at a constant rate, for example, 8 Force per second. You can find this value on your character sheet under Force → Force Regen Rate.

Comment: Bah. I knew it was probably hiding in plain sight like this. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a regen pause after using an item like in similar games with mana or magic? As in, can you regen faster if you go a longer time in between ability, or can you use abilities evenly and still regen at the same constant rate?